# C# - TcpListener - not receiving HTML Request header until refreshing the browser 2 times

Tags: c#

Here is my Socket which is waiting for client to connect ( browser )

```
        Server = new TcpListener(Address, Port);
        Server.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("--- Waiting for the client ----");
        TcpClient client = Server.AcceptTcpClient();
        this.strem = client.GetStream();
        byte[] read = new byte[900];
        this.strem.Read(read, 0, read.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(read));

        this.sendResponseOk();
```

The SendResponseOk Method:

```
        // html
        string htmlResponse = "<html>";
        htmlResponse += "<head><title>ACC Data</title></head>";
        htmlResponse += "<body><h1>ACC Data</h1></body>";
        htmlResponse += "</html>";

        // response header
        string response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
        response += "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
        response += "Content-Length: " + htmlResponse.Length + "\r\n";
        response += "\r\n";
        response += htmlResponse;

        // send
        byte[] sendData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);
        this.strem.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);
```

Where i'm now:

- Starting the Server [work]
- Open the Browser and go to Local Address:Port [Loading]
- Refresh ( hit Enter ) for second time, and i receive the Header [word]
- The HTML page loaded [Work]

The Problem is when i access to Address:Port for the first time and keep loading until i refresh again.

What i have done:

- new Thread.
- change TcpListener to Socket Object.
- Used Thread.Sleep(1000) between every steps.

Thank you.

UPDATE:

On the Phone it works from the first time, no need to refresh the page
maybe something with catch ?

Comment: I have tried with FF and IE, both of them got the response immediately.

Comment: While working with TCP it's typically indicative of a mistake when code fails to capture the integer returned from a Read, which indicates how many bytes were actually read. You have no other reliable way of knowing which index the data in the buffer is valid up to

Comment: Why are you writing your own webserver anyway? Something like Unosquare.EmbedIO invented that wheel already

Comment: @shingo Did you try couple of times or just ones ? .. thank you.

Comment: @CaiusJard i'm getting data from Shared Memory File and i want to take the data to local WebSocket Connection, so i can access it from the phone.

Comment: @obeid_s several times.